# Difference between a Screen and an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

Ive been doing some reading, and got a little confused. In Android development, is there a difference between a Screen and an Activity? What are they? I was reading about an Activity having multiple screens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An activity is a piece of your application which should handle a single specific task (example, receive input from the user or display images or whatever you want).

The part you are referring, "supporting multiple screens" can be explained as a best practice you should follow when developing your application: this is simply the designing of proper layouts based on different possible screen sizes and densities. There is nothing such a "Screen" class in android.

So the relationship between an Activity and the moltitude of screen sizes out there is mapped by the layout XMLs defined in the proper layout folders in your application. The android OS will choose and handle the layout for your activity based on the hardware screen available and the closest-to-best layout you defined.

Think of an activity as a "window" on a desktop OS (like Windows7 or MacOSX or Ubuntu) that allows you to see only one window at a single time. If you have 10 different activities in your app the user may see up to 10 different windows. The android OS will pick the most compatible layout you defined based on the real screen display the user has and places the GUI component accordingly.

Comment: So basically if I have 10 different activities that are shown, the user would be able to navigate 10 "displays" - correct?

I wasnt sure if I was supposed to be structuring my activities to be able to use multiple layouts, cause that is what it sounded like which made entirely no sense. Thanks

Comment: think of an activity as a "window" on a desktop OS (like Windows7 or MacOSX or Ubuntu) that allows you to see only one window at a single time. If you have 10 different activities in your app the user may see up to 10 different windows. The android OS will pick the most compatible layout you defined and places the GUI component accordingly based on the real screen display the user has.

Answer (score 1):

An Android activity **is** the screen you see on your device ie a welcome screen with buttons or whatever. The activity can call other activities which then will show on your device screen. An activity is where you define all your logic for what happens on your device (Of course you can define the layout of your activity in a layout xml file).

Answer (score 0):

An Activity is similar to a form(If you are aware of web development form).

Screen is just displaying activity so there is no object like screen.

For layout control of an Activity you can use main.xml ( Also it can be done using code in your activity extended class.)

Comment: `main.xml` is just the default layout for a project using Eclipse and ADT.